# DC-DC current mode control frequency behavior

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, frequency, buck, stability

On a buck converter in average current control mode, for example, the inner current loop sees and manages the double pole created by the LC filter, and thanks to this the outer voltage loop is blind to this phenomenon ... I'd like to know what the necessary condition is for the external voltage loop to be blind to the double pole? .... if there's a known relationship between the crossover frequency of the inner and outer loop and whether, for the inner loop, we should push the LC pole well outside the Bandwidth (I mean below the 0db gain)?
Any details are welcome, thank you in advance.

To illustrate : From Journal of Kerbala University , Vol. 12 No.3 Scientific . 2014

[image]

Comment: for too incomplete to be an answer - think of the residual phase shift the voltage loop sees at its gain crossover frequency as a result of the current loop activity.

Comment: Good point, I didn’t even think of it